How to add N hours to a time field in LWC
I have a time field on one of the custom objects (it's just a time field, not a date-time one).
I am sending it to LWC it comes in milliseconds like 32400000 which is actually 9 am.
Now on click of a button in the JS handler method, I want to add N number of hours to this value and want to show the same on the UI, but in JS if I try new Date(32400000) it gives an incorrect time and also I have tried setMilliseconds() method of js Date object but still no luck
Can anyone please point me in the right direction of dealing with just the time in javascript as new Date is all about date and date-time?

you can convert your time from milliseconds to hour.
when you add to add N hours, convert the N hours into milliseconds and call the method again to reflect the new time
timeInMilliseconds; // store the time displayed in pure ms form.
timeToShow; // to show to user in a formatted way

handleAddNHours(N){
    if(N > 0){
        const toMilliseconds = (hrs) => (hrs*60*60)*1000;
        this.timeToShow = this.parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(toMilliseconds(N));
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(milliseconds){
  //Get hours from milliseconds
  let hours = milliseconds / (1000*60*60);
  let absoluteHours = Math.floor(hours);
  let h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : '0' + absoluteHours;

  //Get remainder from hours and convert to minutes
  let minutes = (hours - absoluteHours) * 60;
  let absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
  let m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : '0' +  absoluteMinutes;

  //Get remainder from minutes and convert to seconds
  let seconds = (minutes - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
  let absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
  let s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : '0' + absoluteSeconds;   

  return ${absoluteHours ? h + ':' : ''}${m}:${s}    
}

CODE CREDITS:

handleAddNHours - Rahul
parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime - xno and Dan Whitehouse

